# DataBind, DataMember and DataSource is not a memeber of OleDb

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g, dropdownbox, oledbcommand

I have a dropdown list that fills in with the abbreviation of all 50 states from my oracle database.

I am confused why my coding is flagging the following errors:

[image]

I have used this exact coding in another application; however, this one flags the error. Any suggestions?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Class SuppUpdate
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Not States Is Nothing Then

            Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=""*****"";user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd)

            Dim SupplierState As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT column_name FROM table_name order by column_name", conn)
            Dim OracleDataAdapterAds1 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
            OracleDataAdapterAds1.SelectCommand = SupplierState
            Dim DsAds As DataSet = New DataSet
            DsAds.Clear()
            conn.Open()
            If Not (DsAds Is Nothing) Then
                OracleDataAdapterAds1.Fill(DsAds, "table_name")
                SupplierState.DataSource = DsAds
                SupplierState.DataMember = "table_name"
                SupplierState.DataBind()
            End If

        End If
        End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE: made the correction to my DataSource (id of dropdown list) but it fills like so:

[image]

```
If Not StatesList Is Nothing Then

            Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=""****"";user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd)

            Dim SupplierState As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT column FROM table order by column", conn)
            Dim OracleDataAdapterAds1 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
            OracleDataAdapterAds1.SelectCommand = SupplierState
            Dim DsAds As DataSet = New DataSet
            DsAds.Clear()

            If Not (DsAds Is Nothing) Then
                OracleDataAdapterAds1.Fill(DsAds, "table")
                StatesList.DataSource = DsAds
                StatesList.DataMember = "table"
                StatesList.DataBind()
            End If
 End if
```

Comment: `DataBind, DataMember and DataSource` are all properties on `Controls` which support binding.  Binding is not a function of the Data Provider objects

Comment: I see my mistake when comparing my coding for another application that works. All the DataSource..DataMember should be using `States` which is the ID for the dropdownlist. However, when I do I get a `System.Data.DataRowView` that fills the dropdown box ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the `DataValueField = "column"` in the html.

Plus... the DataBind, DataMember and DataSource should use dropdownlist ID.